# TinaCMS/Nextjs github pages 404 when accessing root url in

Tags: next.js, next-router

I just deployed a TinaCMS page on github pages using github actions. It seems to work fine except on initial access to the root URL. On this initial load, Nextjs renders a 404 error page with a link 'Return to home'. When clicking this link, the browser's URL is still the root URL and the home page is rendered correctly.
when I access a sub page like example.com/posts directly, the page is rendered correctly.
when I do a build and export locally and open the files using a local nginx server, the home page is rendered correctly on initial access.
in my next.config.js a have the following:

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/home",
      } ...
```

so what could the problem be in conjunction with github pages?

the complete source code is here: https://github.com/mtnstar/web
the page is accessible on https://mtnstar.net

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix, although the 404 page is flashing up for a second and then the right home age is rendered.
so I added a useEffect hook to initially redirecting to the browser current url.

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles.css";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    router.push(window.location.href)
  },[])
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};
```

so another way to permanently fixing this would be appreciated